# How to set single objects in Angularfire2 - Firebase3

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic2, angularfire, angularfire2

As there is a very poor documentation of Angularfire2, I really cannot figure out how to set single Objects in Angularfire2.
My Database structure is very simple:

```
{
  "mode" : 0
}
```

The "mode" is an integer value.

Before, I was using pure Javascript and Firebase's Web Version but now want to start with hybrid Ionic Apps.
Everywhere are examples and tutorials about database.list but I dont want to work with lists, but only .set or .update the "mode" value.

[Lists work perfectly fine. There is no problem with the general setup.]

My Code Structure:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

import {AngularFire, FirebaseListObservable} from 'angularfire2';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, af: AngularFire) {

  }
}
```

So what would the code be for a simple .set of "mode" to for example integer 2 ?

An answer would be really helpful, I just need to get the hang of the general AngularFire system..

Thanks!

---

Little Side Question:

If I want to call a function from the html by an event. Example button->

```
(click)="setMode(0)"
```

where do I put the actual function in the related typescript code?
Constructor, Component, After?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it as shown below.Hope below code is self-explanatory.

```
        export class YourPage {

          // Ref
          mode: FirebaseObjectObservable<any>;

          constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public af: AngularFire) {

            this.mode = this.af.database.object('/mode');//ref

          }

       setValue(data: any) {
        this.mode.set(data);//set
       }

      updateValue(data: any) {
        this.mode.update(data);//update
      }

     //This is the answer for your 2nd question
     setMode(data):void{
       //method body
     }
 }
```

Comment: Hey Sampath, Thank You so much. Such a great help!